# How to do Laplace transforms?

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform

[image]

The above image is just an example of a piecewise function. From the image you have to write the function and then move things around until you can use some of those Laplace transform equations from the table.

I'm not sure if this is correct for the above, but I got this:

$$f(t)=(t-U)\epsilon(t-2T)$$
where \$\epsilon\$ is the stepfunction.

My main issue is what to do after this. How do I know how I should change this function in order to use one or more of those Laplace equations to get this into the s-domain?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it should be multiplied by a negative step function, as it is cutting it off after 2T

Comment: True. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: In fact it should be also multiplied by positive one to cut off the part before T. I think it might be easier to go with the direct Laplace calculation (that is in it's integral form) here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a single pulse which does not repeat:

Transform the formula of the linear piece (U/T)t-U directly by using the original integral formula of the Laplace transform. Integrate only over time interval T...2T.

You need the integral function of t(exp(-st)). Get it by integrating in parts.

If you have more pieces than this one sawtooth pulse, integrate each of them over their non-zero value time intervals. Add the parts together.

Answer (score 0):

I used MATHCAD 15 to create the required function:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be to perform the integration (i.e. using the definition of the Laplace transform).
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

A more creative way using transformation tables would involve expressing the signal as a linear combination of signals with known transformations. Notice that in our case the signal \$u(t)\$ is given by
$$ u(t) = \frac{U}{T}\cdot [(t -T)\cdot \Theta(t-T) - (t - 2T)\cdot \Theta(t-2T)] - U\cdot \Theta(t-2T)$$
where \$\Theta(t)\$ is the step function. Therefore the laplace transform is given by
$$U(s) = \frac{U}{T}\cdot L(t\Theta(t)) \cdot (e^{-sT} - e^{-2sT}) - U\cdot \frac{e^{-2sT}}{s}.$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on the u(t)? The linear part of the function is (U/T)*t-U right? Which is visible in your function, but I don't quite understand what's happening in your square brackets.

Comment: The first term is the ramp starting at t=T and going to infinity. The second term is again a ramp which starts at t=2T which subtracted from the first ramp. This means that the sum of both shows the "normal" ramp between T and 2T. After 2T the second term cancels the "growth" of the first term such that the sum of bothe is constant with value U after 2T. Finaly tge third term, outside of the square brackets, cancels the exactly the constant remainder after 2T of the sum of the two ramps. Its a lot of words for something that is very visual. Try graphing and graphical addition of the terms.